# How do I find the newest file in a directory using a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

If, for example, I have a directory which contains the following files:

```
Test-20120626-1023.txt
Test-20120626-0710.txt
Test-20120626-2202.txt
Test-20120626-1915.txt
Test-20120626-1142.txt
```

As you can see, each file name contains the time of creation which is in a sortable format.

How do I find the name of the latest file name (in this case `Test-20120626-2202.txt`) and store it in variable?

*Note: The directory path is also stored in a variable if it makes any difference.*

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$dir = "C:\test_code"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.name
```

Comment: And if you want to search for a specific file, change $dir to "C:\test_code\somefile.*"

Comment: and if you want to search all subdirs `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $dir` etc. Also note the -First param in Select-Object selects top k.

Comment: `LastAccessTime`? Shouldn't it be `LastWriteTime`? Or perhaps `CreationTime`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I also had very same question but somehow `LastAccessTime` works for me. Strange!

Comment: @AdamNaylor- is it possible to exclude certain patterns? Like I want .BAK files, but not .TXT files etc.

Answer (score 15):

If the name is the equivalent creation time of the file property `CreationTime`, you can easily use:

```
$a = Dir | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select Name -First 1
```

then

```
$a.name
```

contains the name file.

I think it also works like this if name always have 
the same format (date and time with padding 0, for example, *20120102-0001*):

```
$a = Dir | Sort Name -Descending | Select Name -First 1
```

Answer (score 8):

If you're working with a large number of files, I'd suggest using the `-Filter` parameter as the execution time will be greatly reduced.

Based on the example James provided, here is how it would be used;

```
$dir = "C:\test_code"
$filter="*.txt"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.name
```

Answer (score 7):

If, for some reason, the files creation date is different than the one stamped in the file name then you can parse the file name into a datetime object and sort by expression:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem | 
Sort-Object { [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName,'\Te\s\t\-yyyyMMdd\-HHmm',$null) } |
Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"sort by expression"*?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get last updated files. Easy to write.

```
ls | sort LastWriteTime
```