# How to download newest file from SharePoint using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I'm just curious, do I have any possibility to download the file from SharePoint document library?

The problem is that I have like 3-4 files in this library and I need to get the file with the latest modification date.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the link below, but instead of using the actual SharePoint URL for the directory use the File Explorer address for the SharePoint site.

Powershell Script:

```
$dir = "\\sharepoint.domain.com\site\Foo\SubFoo\SharedDocuments\Folder\"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.name
```

To get the explorer location, right click on a file link in SharePoint, (Firefox 'Copy link location', IE 'Properties').

Copy the URL: http://sharepoint.domain.com/site/Foo/SubFoo/SharedDocuments/Folder/

Change it this format: `\\sharepoint.domain.com\site\Foo\SubFoo\SharedDocuments\Folder\`

Verify the link works: Click 'Start' --> 'Run' --> paste the changed link and run it.  It should open the SharePoint folder.

The PowerShell code came from this site.
Give them a check too:
[How to find newest file in directory using PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210649/how-to-find-newest-file-in-directory-using-powershell-script)