# How to find the most recent modified file in a particular folder using nsis script?

Tags: powershell, nsis

Is it possible to use a [Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210649/how-to-find-newest-file-in-directory-using-powershell-script) inside a .nsh file to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? A simple google search would land you on NSIS homepage with examples of how to execute powershell scripts from the installer

Answer (score 0):

You can call external applications with the `!system` instruction.

This is often combined with `!tempfile` and `!include` to get the output written by the external application:

```
; We need a file in %temp% that the external command can write to.
!tempfile TMPINC

; This !system command tries to find the file in the Windows directory
!system `cd /D %windir% & FOR /F %A IN ('dir /A:-D /T:W /O:D /B') DO @(> "${TMPINC}" echo.!define RECENTMOD "%~fA")` 

!include "${TMPINC}"
!delfile "${TMPINC}"
!undef TMPINC
!ifndef RECENTMOD
!error "No files found!"
!endif

Section
File "${RECENTMOD}"
SectionEnd
```