# Get the latest file from a bunch of similar named files in a directory - powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to get the latest file from the below list.There are 3 types of files created everyday and I just need 1 from the 3 types.

Example:

```
my_file_dob_6545d.txt   12/3/2017 5:00 PM
my_file_csm_6545d.txt   12/3/2017 5:00 PM
my_file_6545d.txt       12/3/2017 5:00 PM  <--- Need to get this.
my_file_dob_6544d.txt   12/2/2017 5:00 PM
my_file_csm_6544d.txt   12/2/2017 5:00 PM
my_file_6544d.txt       12/2/2017 5:00 PM
my_file_dob_6543d.txt   12/1/2017 5:00 PM
my_file_csm_6543d.txt   12/1/2017 5:00 PM
my_file_6543d.txt       12/1/2017 5:00 PM
```

I have the following script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210649/how-to-find-newest-file-in-directory-using-powershell-script)

```
$dir = "c:\my_folder\"
$filter="my_file_*d.txt" <--How can modify this to get only  my_file_XXXXd.txt files? XXXX keeps incrementing everyday
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly simpler syntax:

```
$latest = Get-ChildItem C:\my_folder\my_file_????d.txt | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select -First 1
```

Comment: Cool thanks, was looking for a simpler way to do this.How can I extract the ???? from the file? For example, in my case I need the 6545 extracted.

Comment: You can use the `SubString()` method like: `$latest.Name.Substring(8,4)`. That will skip 8 characters, and return the next 4.

Comment: Ah got it.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, Figured it out myself from an example [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730947.aspx)

```
$dir = "c:\my_folder\"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Where-object { $_.Name -match "my_file_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]d.txt"} | Select-Object -First 1
```