# Is there a way to make a link/symlink/shortcut to the latest file in Windows? Keep tailing the latest log file

Tags: windows, powershell, logging

I searched high and low, found how to do it in *nix, but nothing about Windows.

First place I've seen this was Tomcat's catalina.out, and now I was wondering how to do a similar thing on Windows: considering a folder where log files are created, how to make a file that reads the/points to latest log created?

I'm thinking a Powershell solution might be possible, but I honestly can't think or find any way to do it.

(edit) You guys downvoting could at least leave a comment to tell me what did I do wrong or how can I improve this question?

(edit) The idea here is to have some way to create a symlink that points to the latest log file in a folder, so a program can monitor always the same file, no matter if the latest file changes its name - like `tail -f catalina.out` always reads the latest catalina log file.

The only way out I can see, and that I wanted to avoid, would be to write a powershell script that would monitor a folder (https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created) and would dynamically create a symlink to the latest file found (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11211005/1985023), then set it as a service, so it would be always running on the background.

Comment: Is PowerShell the language/environment you'll be using, or, if not, then what?  Which part are you having issues with, programmatically creating a symlink/shortcut, or determining which among a group of log files is the newest?  I think this question needs more details about what you're working with and what you're trying to do, because, as it stands, potential answers can be simply "Yes".

Comment: Hm... I did understand the problem - I'm a little lost as how to improve it. The point would be to have a single point where a log-reading program would see the latest log by looking at a single file, kinda like "tail -f catalina.out" does, you know?

Comment: I meant to say that what this question needs is your specific requirements, but your latest edit addresses those: 1) a PowerShell script that specifically creates 2) a symlink to be consumed by 3) an application.  Is running a script via a Scheduled Task (run hourly/daily/whatever's appropriate) a possibility?  Or do you need to be absolutely certain there is as little time as possible between a new log being created and the symlink being updated to point to it?  Also, how will the consuming application know to reopen the symlink once it points to a new file (or is that not a concern)?

Comment: It is a possibility, but I think that would fall exactly on the solution scenario that I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Your edit says you want to avoid a service (or otherwise always-running executable) that watches the directory and updates the symlink as soon as a new log file appears.  I'm saying the alternative would be running the script as a Scheduled Task, which would only be running for a few seconds at a time but there'd be greater lag time between a new log appearing and the symlink getting updated to point to it.  You can't avoid both approaches because, unless you control the application creating the logs, I can't think of a third way to trigger the symlink updates.

Comment: hm... I see. No, I don't control the application, but I think I can reach the developer. I'm feeling pretty dumb for not thinking about that before. And yeah, I understand how it can only be service or schedule as a "me-side-only" solution. Thanks @BACON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looking for a dynamically self-updating symlink (which would be quite cumbersome to implement - see the helpful hints from [BACON](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150605/bacon) in the comments in the question), **you can make this work as a self-contained function/script with the help of PowerShell *background jobs***:

- Run in a *loop* that periodically gets the latest log-file lines from a background job that does the equivalent of Unix `tail -f` via `Get-Content -Wait -Tail 10`.
- If a new log file is found, terminate the previous background job and start one for the new log file.

Note that this relies on *periodic polling* of the background job that tails the log. The code below allows you to adjust the polling interval.
Note that `Get-Content -Wait` itself polls the target file for changes every second.

Here's the code; run `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'` to see what's going on inside the loop:

```
$dir = 'C:\path\to\logs' # the log-file directory
$logFilePattern = '*.log' # wildcard pattern matching log files
$sleepIntervalMs = 1000  # how many msec. to sleep between getting new lines from the background job

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Tailing the latest log(s) in $dir...`nPress any key to quit."
$currJob = $currLog = $null
while ($true) {

  # If the user pressed a key, clean up and exit.
  if ([console]::KeyAvailable) {
    $null = [console]::ReadKey($True) # consume the key - it will still have printed, though
    if ($currJob) { Remove-Job -Job $currJob -Force }
    break
  }

  # Get the latest lines from the current log from the background job.
  if ($currJob) {
    Write-Verbose "Checking for new lines in $newLog..."
    Receive-Job -Job $currJob
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $sleepIntervalMs  # sleep a little
  }

  # Determine the first / newest log.
  $newLog = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dir -Filter $logFilePattern | Sort-Object CreationTimeUtc -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
  if ($newLog.FullName -ne $currLog.FullName) { # new log file found.

    Write-Verbose "(New) log file found: $newLog"

    if ($currJob) {
        Write-Verbose "Terminating background job for previous log ($currLog)."
        Remove-Job -Job $currJob -Force
        # When a *new* log was just started, we show *all* lines (and keep listening for more).
        $tailArg = @{} 
    } else {
        # When we first start monitoring, we start with the *last 10* lines
        # of the current log (and keep listening for more).
        $tailArg = @{ Tail = 10 } # On first
    }

    $currLog = $newLog

    Write-Verbose "Starting background job for $currLog..."
    # Start the background job for the new log.
    $currJob = Start-Job { Get-Content -Wait @using:tailArg -LiteralPath $using:newLog.FullName }

  }

}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Terminated."
```